How do I limit smtp servers delivering email by the relay's domain in postfix?
Let's say I have an smtp server and I've setup gmail to relay my mail to it. This server is the final destination. It is not another relay.
Google is the only mx relay I expect to be talking to this port. I'd like to firewall or restrict the port to only google's mail relays.  I could use google's spf to reverse lookup all of the subnets and then add them to my firewall.
Alternatively, can I have my smtp daemon reverse lookup the ip address of the connecting ip and see if it is named *.google.com?
I'm having trouble finding this feature because usually people are filtering by the email's domain.  I want the domain of the ip address connecting to my smtp server.
